# Haskell : error while chaining function using monad

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

The aim of this exercise is to take a list of String and and construct a list of Char, in other words, given a the below list a string

**function  input**

`let input = ["c", "cac", "cb", "bcc", "ba"]`

***applying some behavior***

```
zip' xs = zip xs (tail xs)
let res1 =zip' input
```

after zipping each element in the (*input*) list with the rest of the list, i will get a list of tuple as per the below

```
print res1
res1 =  [("c","cac"),("cac","cb"),("cb","bcc"),("bcc","ba")]
```

***applying some other behavior on res1***

```
zip''  = \(a,b)->zip a b
let res2 = zip'' res1
```

zipping the first and the second item of each pair in the list will get the below list

```
 print res2
    res2 = [[('c','c')],[('c','c'),('a','b')],[('c','b'),('b','c')],[('b','b'),('c','a')]]
```

***applying some other behavior on res2***

```
let finalRes = concat res2
```

**output**

```
print finalRes
finalRes= [('c','c'),('c','c'),('a','b'),('c','b'),('b','c'),('b','b'),('c','a')]
```

***NOW THE MONADIC STYLE***

this problem is obvious to solve it without monad, while I am new to monad and trying to understand it, I have made an attempt to solve it using the bind function `>>=`, I wrote 2 function and bind it together  in order to get from ** input ** to **output** :

```
zip':: [String] -> [(String,String)]
zip' xs = zip xs (tail xs)
```

and

```
zip'' :: ([a], [b]) -> [(a, b)]
zip''  = \(a,b)->zip a b
```

then

`ff =zip'' >>= zip'`

while compiling the code I got an error in the function ff that type do not align.

let me re-write the bind signature

```
Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

applying  `ff ["c", "cac", "cb", "bcc", "ba"]`

as I have understood, that the `zip'` takes a list of String and return a list of pair which is a **context** of pair so it is the first argument `m a` for the bind operator which shouhld align with  the second function `zip''`.
so the function `zip''` will take each pair/tuple and apply its behavior in order to return the concatenated list of Char.

what Have I miss , and what is wrong in the code?

*sorry for the long question*

Comment: It is difficult to determine what you are trying to achieve. Could you rephrase your question, such that it is clear what you are trying to achieve? Maybe even just an example input with an associated desired output?

Comment: thanks for your interest, hope it is clear now

Comment: `zip''` takes a `(String, String)` argument, but `res1 :: [(String, String)]`. You would have to run `map zip'' res1` to get the `res2` that you show.

Comment: `zip'`, by the way, can be written more succinctly as `zip <*> tail`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ff` function is backwards. You should start with `zip'` and bind to `zip''` like this:

```haskell
ff list = zip' list >>= zip''
```

Running it through the REPL gives you:

```haskell
> let zip' xs = zip xs (tail xs)
> let zip'' = \(a,b)->zip a b
> let ff list = zip' list >>= zip''
> ff ["c", "cac", "cb", "bcc", "ba"]
[('c','c'),('c','c'),('a','b'),('c','b'),('b','c'),('b','b'),('c','a')]
```